# Changing the formula in a table from a specific row on in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have an Excel table with formulas. When I add a new row to the table, the formulas will automatically be added to the new row. This is normally desirable since it eliminate the need to write the formulas each time. Now I need to change the formula, but this formula should only affect the rows that will be added from now on and don't change the calculation of the rows above.

Is there any trick to that? Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Not a real answer to the question, but would clicking `ctrl+d` solve your issue? (copy from cell above). It would copy the formula from the cell above (not tested).

Comment: @P.b Sir, I agree with you, that `CTRL+D` would fill up the cells with the formula but it still misses the autofill nature of `Structured References` it wont work.

Comment: Just for clarification, I meant to say, when we enter any formula in a `Structured References` usually it fills down automatically without any manual intervention, however if the formula I have commented wont fill down automatically, and needs to be filled down manually. So that said, the auto fill nature of `Structured References` aka `Tables` is missing or wont work!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this where you test to see which row of the table you are currently in:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])<=10,[@x]*2,[@x]*3)
```

So for the first ten rows the formula in column y is 2x, then after that it's 3x.

[image]

Comment: Sir got inspired by your solution, if there are more than once then may be OP could do something like this, : `=LOOKUP(ROW()-ROW(Table11[[#Headers],[y]]),{1,4,9,13},{0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5})`

Comment: This solution to me says you want me to have my formulas in two different columns and choose which one applies based on the rows. Am I correct?

Comment: No, it's just a single formula entered in the first cell under the header of column y in the table - it chooses one of two possible formulas using an if statement, depending on the row which is filled.

Answer (score 1):

Change your formula so that it does a separate calculation based on whatever change you're trying to account for. Without seeing your data, I can't be more specific, but...

If you can move some part of the formula out of the formula, do that. So `=[@Amount]*1.2` gets changed to `[@Amount]*1.4`, and that starts on 1/1/2023, you could create another table with the effective date and the rate, and change the formula to `[@Amount]*VLOOKUP([@Date],tblRates,2,TRUE)` for example.

How easy that is depends on what in your data changes to trigger the formula change.

Formulas in tables are fickle, at least in 2019 (the version I'm using). If you have any inconsistencies in the column, you could lose the ability for the formula to autofill in new rows. And even if you don't lose that, it's hard to predict which version of the formula will fill in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My formulas read data from another table in another sheet to fill the cells. Old formula is '=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Serial Number]], Asset_list!$A$2:$F$2975, 5, FALSE),"")' and new formula is ''=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Serial Number]], Asset_list!$A$2:$H$2975, 7, FALSE),"")="",IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Serial Number]], Asset_list!$A$2:$H$2975, 5, FALSE),""),IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Serial Number]], Asset_list!$A$2:$H$2975, 7, FALSE),""))'. As  you see this very hard to incorporate part of them outside.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > options > proofing` then click on `AutoCorrect Options..` button.
in Auto correct window go to `Auto format as you type` tab an uncheck as show in picture.

[image]

this is prevent excel to automatically change other table rows.